# Why can't you use @autoclosure on a typealias to a function closure type?

Tags: swift, swift3, type-alias

Kinda surprised on this one.  In Swift 3, this code compiles...

```
class func test(foo:@autoclosure () -> Void)
{
}
```

but this doesn't...

```
typealias VoidHandler = () -> Void

class func test(foo:@autoclosure VoidHandler)
{
}
```

You get...

```
error: @autoclosure attribute only applies to function types
```

Why not?  It seems like it's an alias to the exact same thing, no?

Comment: You're right Marquel, this has been reported as a bug in Swift 3 here: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2688.  For now, you'll have to work around it by declaring @autoclosure with the actual closure type (e.g. () -> String) instead of using the alias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is (was!) a bug in the Swift compiler and has been fixed as of Swift 5.1.  You can read more about the bug and see the fix here: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2688.